# Selenium IDE select using css not working

Tags: css, selenium-ide

I am using the Selenium IDE and Firefox v54.xx.
I can select an element using the following:

```
Command = Select 
Target = id=DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_6 
Value = EDR-20
```

(Not sure why the overflow editor sees the above as code?)

but when I try and select it using ccs it fails

```
ccs=input#DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_6
```

I am trying to use the ccs as the ID keeps changing

```
id=DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_1   
id=DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_2
```

etc.

So I have tried using the CCS which keeps returning and [error] locator not found:....
I have tried the following for taget:

```
css=input[id^='DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_']  
css=input[id^='DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_'][type='commonTextBoxStyle ddl250 DsnDrawing_DrawingRef']  
css=input."commonTextBoxStyle ddl250 DsnDrawing_DrawingRef"  
css=input.'commonTextBoxStyle ddl250 DsnDrawing_DrawingRef'  
ccs=input#DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_6  
id^=DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_
```

Web page requires a login so I cannot share, code snippet is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="t-ff t-ff54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body id="ctl00_masterBody" onkeydown="hotkey(event)" onkeyup="hotkey(event, true)">
<div id="ctl00_divPageWrap" class="page_wrap">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="editPopupDsnDrawing" class="edit_popup" style="height: auto; width: 500px; z-index: 3000; overflow: scroll; position: absolute; left: 269.5px; top: 351.5px; display: block;">
<div id="errorDsnDrawing" class="divError" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="popup_body">
<table style="border:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Drawing Ref</td>
<td>
<select id="DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_6" class="commonTextBoxStyle ddl250 DsnDrawing_DrawingRef" data-val="" data-displayval="" style="background-color: rgb(241, 242, 244);">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table></table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="loadingDiv" class="loadingDiv" style="left: 371px; top: 300px; z-index: 10000; display: none;">
<div id="PopupTransparent" style="opacity: 0.5; height: 1435px; width: 99%; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; background: rgb(244, 242, 239) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; z-index: 2999;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the tag here is "Select", not "input".

```
css=input[id^='DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_']
```

did not work.

```
css=select[id^=DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New]
```

Works (Note difference is "select" instead of "input")

html code in this instance is:

```
<select id="DsnDrawing_DrawingRef_New_6" class="commonTextBoxStyle ddl250 DsnDrawing_DrawingRef" data-val="" data-displayval="" style="background-color: rgb(241, 242, 244);">
```

Target Format: css=tag#id or css=tag[id=id] where tag is "select" in this case.